# Natural isomorphism between curve and its projective completion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $C \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ is an irreducible affine curve and $\hat{C} \subset \mathbb{P}_2$ is its projective completion, is there necessarily a natural isomorphism of function fields $K_C \cong K_{\hat{C}}$? Why would this hold/not hold intuitively? What does this look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field of rational functions of an irreducible curve (or more generally algebraic variety) $X$ is the same as that of any of its non-empty open subsets $U$.
In other words the restriction morphism $\mathscr K(X)\stackrel {\cong} {\to} \mathscr K(U)$ is a field isomorphism.
The   reason for that is that "rational functions" are (by definition)  actually not functions on $X$  but functions on some open subset of $X$.
From a more  advanced point of view we may say that the sheaf $\mathscr K_X$ of rational functions on $X$ is a constant sheaf, which has the interesting consequence that $\mathscr K_X$ is flabby and thus has no cohomology in positive degree.